# Starting from one point, find the nearest two points that meet the requirements

Tags: python, algorithm

I started from the "start" node and wanted to find Element1 and Element2. If I look for the Shortest  distance every time, I may find node 4 and then node 7, but the total number of hops is 4.  This is not a global optimum, so how can I find the Global optimal solution, nodes 2 and 3?
[image: linear graph: (3/elem2) (2/elem1) (1) (start) (4/elem1) (5) (6) (7/elem2)]

Comment: Do a breadth-first search, keep track of the elements you have seen and stop when you have seen them all?

Answer (score 1):

You have to save this first number of hops you find with your method and do this for the next shortest distance to an Element1 again. If this total number of hops is smaller than the first you save this one. If not, you keep the first number.